# Is it good programming practice to decorate functions in bash/korn script

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I've a scenario where I've to check the input argument for non-zero size everytime I pass it to a function. I can't add the check within the function itself. I was looking into something like this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125819/bash-function-decorator

I've to use the function in quite a few places so I don't want to use an if-condition everytime i call the function. Is using a docorator in the fashion given in the link a good way to do it?

Comment: I'd rather live with a little bit of explicit duplicated code than trust that `decorate` is implemented safely and correctly.

Comment: What do you do if the argument is zero-sized?

Comment: I would like the script to just go to success without doing anything in case of zero argument

Comment: In that case, just use `[[ -z $value ]] || somefunc "$value"`.

Comment: It's not quite the same thing, but you might find the implementation of postconditions in https://github.com/threatgrid/declarative.bash interesting. That said, even as its author, I don't consider such tools to be the Right Thing for every job (or even most).

Comment: ...also, you'll note that my version almost entirely avoids magic with eval (and, where it _does_ use eval, goes to substantial pains to do so safely).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you - great contribution!

Comment: For the record we picked away at a "well-decorated" bash script today. We found between 15 to 20 severe errors in it, due to weakly defined post conditions etc. My feeling is: apply these methods _after_ you got good at shell scripting, not from the start. Otherwise it'll be mostly a pile of well-meaning esoteric features with little effect.

Answer (score 2):

I'd feel much better about my code with

```
[[ -n $value ]] && somefunc "$value"
```

or

```
somefunc "${value:-defaultvalue}"
```

than trusting that I (or someone else) got the `eval` magic right in an attempt to write a function decorator that redefines `somefunc` so that

```
somefunc "$value"
```

does the same thing automatically.

I would probably either copy the function into my own script and add the parameter check, or define a simple wrapper:

```
somefunc_with_type_check () {
    if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
        # take necessary action
    fi
    somefunc "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For **debugging purposes** you can use some check function when calling your `somefunc`, like

```
somefunc "$a" #your current calling
#change it to
somefunc "$(cz a)"   #call the cz function for Checking Zero on variable "a"
```

Your check function could call stack dumping and such things, e.g. the next example

```
dumpstack() {
    echo "ARG ERROR: $@" >&2
    local i=0
    for(( i=${#BASH_LINENO[@]}-2; i>=0; i-- ))
    do
        printf "\tFile:%s line:%s func:%s\n"  "${BASH_SOURCE[i+1]}" "${BASH_LINENO[i]}"  "${FUNCNAME[i+1]}" >&2
    done
}

cz() {
    [[ -n "${!1}" ]] || dumpstack "zero arg $1"   #indirect variable checking
    echo "${!1}"
}

somefunc() {
    echo "got this ==$1=="
}

a=
somefunc "$(cz a)"  #warns on zero length

a=5
somefunc "$(cz q)"  #warns on mistyped variable

somefunc "$(cz a)"  #ok
```

prints

```
ARG ERROR: zero arg a
    File:y line:20 func:main
    File:y line:11 func:cz
got this ====
ARG ERROR: zero arg q                #<-- shows the used variable name
    File:y line:23 func:main
    File:y line:11 func:cz
got this ====
got this ==5==
```